# What color should the face orientation be on the inside and the outside?

Tags: normals

According to [this](https://youtu.be/Np1kscimD4w?si=6ifWh9QW6mpBMvK3&t=2307) tutorial

> Everything outside should be blue and everything inside should be red

[image: 1st tutorial image]

But in [this](https://youtu.be/DJRBv917CI0?si=Dl8Sb_FxLVUVj7Bf&t=139) tutorial

> It should be blue on the inside and red on the outside

[image: 2nd tutorial image]

Comment: Front of a face is blue, back of a face is Red. There is no in and out is more about front (face pointing to the camera) and back of a face (not pointing to the camera)

Comment: You are misinterpreting the explanations. As @Emir said, it is more about front and back of a face. Blue **always** the front and red **always** the back. And if you have a closed object like a cube, preferably the front is on the outside and the back on the inside (because some shaders can look unexpected or weird from the backside). **But:** Andrew is talking about the inside of the room, not (wrongly) the inside of a face. Because when inside the room, looking at a wall it is better to look at the front of the face for material shading reasons like bump etc. (as he says in the tutorial)

Comment: Additional note: if you make the walls like real walls with a thickness instead of only thin faces, then you can actually have the outside and inside of the house or room blue.